# Select query in pymysql

Tags: python, sql, pymysql

When executing the following:

```
import pymysql 



db = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root')
cur = db.cursor()    
print(cur.execute("SELECT ParentGuardianID FROM ParentGuardianInformation WHERE UserID ='" + UserID + "'"))
```

The output is`1`

How could I alter the code so that the actual value of the ParentGuardianID (which is '001') is printed as opposed to `1`.

I'm sure the answer is simple but I am a beginner so any help would be much appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`cur.execute()` just returns the number of rows affected. You should do `cur.fetchone()` to get the actual result, or `cur.fetchall()` if you are expecting multiple rows.

Answer (score 24):

The `cursor.execute()` method gives out a cursor related to the result of the SQL sentence. In case of a `select` query, it returns the rows (if any) that meet it. So, you can iterate over these rows using a `for` loop for instance. In addition, I would recommend you to use `pymysql.cursors.DictCursor` because it allows treating the query results as a dictionary.

```
import pymysql 
db = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root')
cur = db.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

UserId = 'whatsoever'
sql = "SELECT ParentGuardianID FROM ParentGuardianInformation WHERE UserID ='%s'"
cur.execute(sql % UserId)
for row in cur:
    print(row['ParentGuardianID'])
```

Good luck!

Comment: `cur.execute(sql, UserId)` is better than `cur.execute(sql % UserId)` since you are leveraging to function to sanitize the input rather than just use python string formatting.